# jQuery Address in Symfony 2

Tags: jquery, url, symfony

I try to convert my Symfony 2.0 website to an ajax crawl website like Deezer, Grooveshark, Ubster... with Asual's jQuery Address `#!`.

But when I try to implement it, all pages reload instantly again and again ... Probably because all ajax call of render includes the layout which includes the JS Address and so try to call again and so on.

I don't know how to correctly integrate this plugin in Symfony 2. Maybe you have a different proposition for doing a crawl like Deezer and cie.

I'm uysing [jQuery Address](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/).

Comment: This is difficult to answer without seeing your current implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Just by using JQuery ajax to call an url that you've defined to render a view containing only the wanted content without the global template.